How do I render a shortcode inside HTML in wordpress?
I have a database of locations that includes the street address as well as latitude and longitude. I want to display a map based on the lat/long on each location's page. This is what I have, which I know doesn't work:
How can I get the shortcodes to output their HTML so that they can be used in an instance like this?
I've tried a couple variations of code, which I have pieced together from different threads, but none of the answers fit my exact request.
Ex:
<?php
$shortcode = do_shortcode('[ASL_STORE field="long"]');
$content = '. $longitude .';
return $content;
?>
<?php
$shortcode = do_shortcode('[ASL_STORE field="lat"]');
$content = '. $latitude .';
return $content;
?>
<iframe width="300" height="220" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key=myapikey&location='$latitude',$'longitude'&heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35" >
 </iframe>


Make sure that

you do not assign all the shortcodes to the same $shortcode variable because then you will override previous values and lose them
you properly initialize $latitude and $longitude
you do not return when you do not need to

<?php
$longitude = do_shortcode('[ASL_STORE field="long"]');
$latitude = do_shortcode('[ASL_STORE field="lat"]');
?>
<iframe width="300" height="220" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key=myapikey&location='<?php echo $latitude; ?>','<?php echo $longitude; ?>'&heading=210&pitch=10&fov=35" >
 </iframe>


I'm using wordpress, and for whatever reason, the PHP script is not processing first. What am I doing wrong?

@AnyaCurry why do you think that and what is being executed before?

When I use the coding above, the output is still


The page doesn't seem to recognize the php output to use in the iframe. I didn't know if this was because it's wordpress? Is there some other way I should implement it?

@AnyaCurry what is the name of the file where you have this iframe displayed?
